# How to find the lowest, highest and average values in a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, average, highest

I'm trying to create a program that calculates and displays the highest, lowest and average value of items in a listbox (items generated from a txt file). I finally figured out how to load a text file to the listbox. I have been searching for clues for about an hour and all my attempts have brought me to a dead end.

my listbox is called readListbox and my Highest, Lowest and Average labels are called highestLabel, lowestLabel and averageLabel respectively. How do I go about creting this program. The numbers are in the decimal format. Any Help will be very much appreciated.

```
private void readButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if(Open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            readListbox.Text = Open.FileName;
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Open.FileName);
            readListbox.Items.AddRange(lines);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What kind of values are stored in your file? I suppose that you have just numbers there right? Are they integers or decimals?

Comment: they are decimals, thanks!

Comment: why do you have extra `}` and `{` in your code.. ? also I would recommend storing the values in an array that you read from the file and use the Array.Min, Array.Max functions and for the Average look at using a lambda expression.. there are plenty of working examples as well as many different ways to skin this cat..

Comment: I'm not very good at arrays at all, let alone c#. I only know the very basics of Listboxes which Is why I decided to use the more familiar approach. Will check it out when I have more time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the string elements of your file you need to convert them to decimal values. At that point you can use the built in methods of the IEnumerable extensions to get your data

```
OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog();
if(Open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
        readListbox.Text = Open.FileName;
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Open.FileName);

        decimal[] values = lines.Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).ToArray();
        labelHigh.Text = values.Max().ToString();
        labelMin.Text = values.Min().ToString();
        labelAvg.Text = values.Average().ToString();        

        readListbox.Items.AddRange(lines);
 }
```

Comment: Hi I don't completely understand your explanation, this is due to my lack of programming knowledge/ terminology. I've copied the code above to my program and I get 2 errors:

1.A local or parameter named 'lines' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

2. The name 'Open' does not exist in the current context

Comment: The code above replaces the code inside your existing if block. Answer edited to be more clear